Variable importance in cluster analysis
I'm new to the cluster analysis, read lots of things but I'm not able to understand how to variables are ordered into cluster. I mean, I find that my data are clustered into 3 different cluster, but how can I understand which of my variables are the most relevant to asses this result? I use R and there are lots of package to perform cluster analysis, but in the functions manuals I haven't found anything related to the importance of the variables. Can someone try to explain it to me? Thanks in advance
EDIT:
For example, I do cluster analysis using k-means, on a data set that has 40 rows (different sample) and 30 columns (feature, numerical variable). How can I determine which of this 30 feature are the most important / dominant / relevant to determine the final clustering result? I suppose that not all the feature bring relevant information. Such as in supervised machine learning but have no prior information on the data structure/class. Could be a right approach to do a supervised model based on the results of cluster analysis, using the cluster as class to which a sample belongs and building a model on it?

Cluster analysis is a huge bunch of different programs. The two most common general categories are aggolmerative (aka hierarchical) and k-means, but, within those, there are many choices. Which one are you interested in?  (Also, your question may not have an answer).

This discussion may help some, and provide some references.

@Sointu thanks, I will take a look.

@PeterFlom Iuse both hierarchical cluster than k-means. And I arrive always at this question without an answer

Also for k-means clustering, I think this R package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FeatureImpCluster/readme/README.html helps with what you want.

You need to be specific and quantitative about what you mean by "relevant" before you can even formulate this problem in a solvable form.  But once you do, in principle it's a matter of evaluating the quality of the clustering (with a suitable numerical quantity) and comparing the quality of clustering you achieve upon eliminating one variable at a time: the one that reduces the quality the most is arguably the "most relevant."  To get beyond such generalities, you need to provide more information, including what clustering method you are using.

@Sointu very enteresting reading!
